# Any way to override arguments' getter/setter nature?

Tags: javascript, arguments

As I just found out:  if a function is defined with a parameter signature, using those parameter names will also change the value accessed using `arguments`.  Is there a way around this.  And are there other JavaScript special cases like this?
e.g:

```
function fn(a) {
    a = "changed";
    console.log(arguments[0]);//changed
}

fn("initial");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the quirks carried over from older generations of javascript engines to not break backwards compatibility, you may ["use strict";](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) to avoid such things as well as many others. If you have a "*grown*" codebase you may want to apply "use strict" only in a specific function scope to avoid breaking your application, though the better way would be to update all your code to be strict mode compatible.

For a complete list of quirky behaviors disabled by the "use strict" statement see the list of [changes in strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Changes_in_strict_mode).

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    function fn(a) {
        a = "changed";
        console.log(arguments[0]);//initial
    }
    fn("initial");
})();
```

Comment: Do you know of any other quirky behaviors similar to this?

Comment: They're listed on the MDN page linked in my answer. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: `function fn(a) { "use strict"; … }` should be enough. No need for the IIFE.

Comment: It is, i chose to use the IIFE to support the *grown codebase* aspect of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a copy of the `arguments` object at the beginning of the function and then the copy will be immune from assigning a new value to the named arguments.

Or, if you put that function in `strict` mode, the arguments object is no longer aliased by the named arguments so it will not change if something is assigned to a named argument.  You can see the comments [on this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Making_eval_and_arguments_simpler) about the `arguments` object in strict mode for further info.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

`arguments` is a local variable of the function and is similar to an array. It contains an entry for each argument passed into the function. If you change the value if one of these arguments then `arguments` will have the updated value as well.

You could copy arguments to an array before making changes:

```
function fn(a) {
var originalArgumentValues = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
a = "changed";
console.log(arguments[0]);//changed
console.log(originalArgumentValues[0]);//inital
};

fn("initial");
```

As others posted, `'use strict'` is another way around this.